# Why can the winforms unhandled exception box sometimes continue?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I've recently switched over to handling my unhandled exceptions this way:

```
Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

This will be nice for logging and what not, but I've lost the ability of the old unhandled exception box to 'continue'. My current handler just prompts for a restart. A lot of the time, clicking continue in that unhandled exception box actually keeps the program running just fine. How does this work? Is there a way I can allow 'continuing' with the way I'm catching the unhandled exceptions now? Say if the exception is of a certain type, could I attempt to 'continue' just like the unhandled exception box does? Or is this not possible?

Does anybody out there understand the nuts and bolts of the world of exceptions? Would love to hear your guys' thoughts.

Comment: Please delete this question, I didn't notice right away that when I catch the exceptions like this it does appear to continue the way the unhandled box does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application is terminated because this is the  default behaviour of CLR. If you have an exception that is unhandled, this means you have a critical flaw in your program and the best handling for such situation is to close  the whole app.

There is a technique, however, if you want to continue after such unhandled exception. You can create a second domain in your application and load libraries there. Exceptions within different app domains are independent. Check out my [blog entry](http://blog4work.com/post/2011/04/13/NET-CLR-AppDomain-features.aspx) on this, there is some sample code available.